# How do I maintain and save custom cell textfield entry data when scrolling cells deque

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, tableview, custom-cell

Sadly I know what the issue is however I'm green and don't know the best way to go about handling it.  I have read the apple documentation and all the related questions here and cant find or interpret the info sufficiently.

As you will see below.  I have a tableview with 19 cells. 2 in section 0, 17 in section 1.  Everything works fine except for when I scroll,  I know this is because the tableview is reusing the cells, so when I try to save as seen in my code below these cells simply don't exist and therefore anything that is not in my view when I attempt to save is a nil string argument and so my entity ends up NaN.

What would be the appropriate approach to maintaining and saving the textfield info from all of my cells?  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
    UITableViewCell *newCell;

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"RNDateCell";
    RNCommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"RNCommentCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.commentLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Date:", @"Date:");
        cell.commentField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.timeStamp.description];
        newCell = cell;
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"RNCommentCell";
    RNCommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"RNCommentCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.commentLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Comment:", @"Comment:");
        cell.commentField.text = self.metrics.comment;
        newCell = cell;
    }
}

if (indexPath.section == 1) {
    static NSString *numericCellIdentifier = @"RNNumericCell";
    RNNumericCell *cell = (RNNumericCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:numericCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"RNNumericCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Weight:", @"Weight:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.weight];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 1:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Height:", @"Height:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.height];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 2:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Neck:", @"Neck:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.neck];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 3:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Chest:", @"Chest:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.chest];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 4:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Waist:", @"Waist:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.waist];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 5:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hips:", @"Hips:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.hips];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 6:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Biceps:", @"Biceps:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.biceps];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 7:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Forearms:", @"Forearms:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.forearms];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 8:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Wrists:", @"Wrists:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.wrists];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 9:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Quads Thighs:", @"Quads Thighs:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.quadsThighs];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 10:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Calves:", @"Calves:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.calves];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 11:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Ankles:", @"Ankles:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.ankles];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 12:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Feet:", @"Feet:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.feet];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 13:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"BMI:", @"BMI:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.bmi];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 14:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"BMR:", @"BMR:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.bmr];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 15:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Waist/Height R:", @"Waist/Height R:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.waistToHeightRatio];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            case 16:
                cell.numericCellLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Waist/Hips R:", @"Waist/Hips R:");
                cell.numericField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.metrics.waistToHipRatio];
                newCell = cell;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
return newCell;
```

}

```
    - (void)saveData
```

{

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
RNCommentCell *dateCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
self.metrics.timeStamp = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateCell.commentField.text];

RNCommentCell *commentCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
self.metrics.comment = commentCell.commentField.text;


RNNumericCell *weightCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.weight = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:weightCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *heightCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.height = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:heightCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *neckCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.neck = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:neckCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *chestCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.chest = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:chestCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *waistCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.waist = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:waistCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *hipsCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:5 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.hips = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:hipsCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *bicepsCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:6 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.biceps = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:bicepsCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *forearmCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:7 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.forearms = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:forearmCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *wristsCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:8 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.wrists = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:wristsCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *quadsCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:9 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.quadsThighs = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:quadsCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *calvesCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:10 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.calves = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:calvesCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *anklesCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:11 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.ankles = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:anklesCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *feetCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:12 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.feet = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:feetCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *bmiCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:13 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.bmi = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:bmiCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *bmrCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:14 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.bmr = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:bmrCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *waistToHeightCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:15 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.waistToHeightRatio = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:waistToHeightCell.numericField.text];

RNNumericCell *waistToHipCell = (id)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:16 inSection:1]];
self.metrics.waistToHipRatio = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:waistToHipCell.numericField.text];

NSError *error;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `UITextField`'s are views, and should not be storing data but instead simply displaying/retrieving it.  Your model (`self.metrics`) should be where you store the information, and it should be stored as soon as you receive it from the user so that it doesn't matter if the text field goes away or gets reused.

In order to do that, you use the following method which is called whenever someone stops editing a text field (make sure that you set the delegate of all of your text field's to your controller):

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Figure out which textField this is and save the data to the appropriate place in your model
}
```

Now, the slightly tricky part is figuring out which text field you are working with in this method.

You can set the tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and then lookup the tag number here to determine which it is, or you can do it by index path since that is what you are doing already anyway:

```
CGRect position = [self convertRect:textField.frame toView:self.tableView];
NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForRowsInRect:position];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much this has helped me see the proper way to implement it.   I wasn't quite smart enough to figure out how to use the index code you provided.  However simply adding cell.texfield.tag = XXXX for each of the rows in my cell for index path, then referring to said cell in texfielddidendediting to save the data to my model is easy enough for me to follow and works great, hopefully this is an approved and efficient enough method.  Cheers and thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome!  You use the indexPath in the same way that you did in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Either way is a perfectly valid way of doing it though!   As you are new to the site, be sure to up vote ALL answers that helped you (whether you asked the question or not)  by clicking the up arrow next to it. :)

Comment: Thanks much, now that I have the reputation I will do that!

Answer (score 2):

Update your `self.metrics.'whatever'` data whenever it's changed and only save the metrics in your `save` instead of trying to grab it from cells.  In other words, don't use the cell as a data storage location.

Comment: Thank you this it helps put things in a better perspective for me. Now just to implement it.